# Accepting input till newline in python

Tags: python

I am a python beginner. I am trying to accept inputs from the user as long as he/she wishes. The program should stop accepting inputs when the enter key alone is pressed.

That is

```
25
65
69
32 
   #stop here since the enter key was pressed without any input
```

I came up with the following code of doing that....

```
a = []
while 1:

    b = input("->")
    if(len(b)>0):
        a.append(b)
    else:
        break
```

---

1. Is there any other efficient 'pythonic' ways of doing this ?
2. While this works perfectly with python 3.3 it doesnt work with python 2.7 (with input() replaced by the raw_input() function). The screen just stays dumb without any response. Why is that?
3. Is there any inbuilt function with which i can convert strings back to integers!?

Comment: No need for parenthesis around the if statement, use `int('string')` to change a string to an integer

Comment: Please watch out with whitespaces in Python. I realized that your code example mixes tabs and common spaces.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your approach is mostly fine. You could write it like this:

```
a = []
prompt = "-> "
line = input(prompt)

while line:
    a.append(int(line))
    line = input(prompt)

print(a)
```

**NB:** I have not included any error handling.

As to your other question(s):

1. `raw_input()` should work similarly in Python 2.7
2. `int()` -- Coerves the given argument to an integer. It will fail with a `TypeError` if it can't.

For a Python 2.x version just swap `input()` for `raw_input()`.

Just for the sake of education purposes, you could also write it in a **Functional Style** like this:

```
def read_input(prompt):
    x = input(prompt)
    while x:
        yield x
        x = input(prompt)


xs = list(map(int, read_input("-> ")))
print(xs)
```

Comment: Using a lot of functions doesn't make anything "functional" or "functional style" (in the sense of the functional paradigm). Functinal programming using iteration instead of recursion is quite ... interesting

Comment: IT is still "functional" in the sense that it uses functions to wrap functionality and iterate of the results. Wrapping the side-effect producing ``input()`` function.

Comment: It's certainly not strictly pure functional however :)

Comment: Also bear in mind that the built-in `iter` takes a sentinel argument and does the same thing as your generator. So it boils down to `[int(x) for x in iter(lambda: input('-> '), '')]`.

Comment: Well yeah. But that's probably going a bit too far right? :) I mean a line-liner? :)

Answer (score 8):

Probably the slickest way that I know (with no error handling, unfortunately, which is why you don't see it too often in production):

```
>>> lines = list(iter(input, ''))
abc
def
.
g

>>> lines
['abc', 'def', '.', 'g']
```

This uses the two-parameter call signature for `iter`, which calls the first argument (`input`) until it returns the second argument (here `''`, the empty string).

Your way's not too bad, although it's more often seen under the variation

```
a = []
while True:
    b = input("->")
    if not b:
        break
    a.append(b)
```

Actually, use of `break` and `continue` is one of the rare cases where many people do a one-line `if`, e.g.

```
a = []
while True:
    b = input("->")
    if not b: break
    a.append(b)
```

although this is Officially Frowned Upon(tm).

Answer (score 1):

1. idk, this code looks good for me.
2. it works perfectly on my python 2.7.5, with raw_input()
3. just use int() function: for example, int('121') returns 121 as integer

Answer (score 0):

As a matter of code style, I always prefer loops without breaks. In my humble opinion the most human readable version would then be (Python 3):

```
a=[]
for line in iter(input, ''):
    a.append(line)
```