# raw_input isn't receiving too much input

Tags: python, input

This is a pretty cool code except for raw_input isn't receiving too much input i want to receive input like 5000 chars help any ideas please quick

```
 import re
    test_cases =  int(raw_input(""))
    input_lens = raw_input("")
    i = 0
    for i in range(0,test_cases+1):
        user_input = raw_input("")
        user_input = re.findall("\d*",user_input)
        count = 0
        for item in user_input:
            if item.isdigit():
                count += 1
        print count
        i += 1
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: Also, please note that this is *not* a time-critical consulting service.  If you have an immediate need, perhaps you should go to a more active Q&A site; SO is built as a solutions archive.

Comment: Finally, please describe your problem as outlined in the posting guidelines: input you gave, result, result you want, and progress in your debugging work.

Comment: perhaps you are wanting to use `sys.stdin.read()` which will read until EOF ... `raw_input` will only read until a linebreak is encountered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As from the docs for `raw_input()` at https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input

> The function then reads a line from input, converts it to a string **(stripping a trailing newline)**, and returns that.

`raw_input()` does not take anything after the newline/linebreak.

Comment: i know is there is another way of taking the input after the newline/linebreak

Comment: @YossefNagy I think this answer might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20511221/3194722 :)

Comment: Thanks that helped

Comment: Awesome. If you liked the responses you could upvote and accept this as the answer to close the question, please.