# taking multiple line input in python without using list comprehensions?

Tags: python, list, input

> without knowing the 'size' how to take multi-line input and store it in a list ?

```
1
2
3
4  

>   list=[]
>   size=int(input())
>   for i in range(size):
>      list.append(int(input()))
```

Comment: How do you know when you've reached the end of the input?

Comment: Assuming keyboard input: you read one line at a time, each line is terminated by Enter. You'll need a stop condition, for example an empty input.

Comment: list=[int(x) for x in input.split()] , i want something like this here also end of input is not specified.

Comment: `input.split()` doesn't make sense: `AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'split'`

Comment: If you want to read _everything_ you can read `sys.stdin`, but the user will need to send the End of File code, on Unix-like systems you can do that with Ctrl-D.

Comment: If end of input is not specified, then how do you know when to stop reading?

Comment: @i-Gagan i updated my answer

Comment: You are contradicting yourself... First you say that the length of the input is not specified, but your example code seems to expect the length of the input as first value. Then you say that you don't want to use list comprehensions, but then show a list comprehension as your desired code.

Comment: @mkrieger1 , 'examle code'  and 'list comprehensions'  are the two ways that i know and they both are not working here. i need to take input till a blank line appears.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20511159/accepting-input-till-newline-in-python or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20337489/python-how-to-keep-repeating-a-program-until-a-specific-input-is-obtained

Comment: "i need to take input till a blank line appears. " You **really** should have mentioned that in your question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
result = []
while True:
    item = input()
    if not item:
        break
    result.append(int(item))
```