# How to read from user input until newline is found in Python?

Tags: python, user-input

I want to take unknown number of positive and negative integer number from user. The input will stop when the user press the Enter key.

For example -
If an user enter `1 2 3 4 5 -9 -10 1000 -Enter Key-` 
 then it will store `"1 2 3 4 5 -9 -10 1000"`

Here is my tried code -

```
a = []
inp = input()

while inp != "\n":
    a.append(inp)
    inp = input()

print(a)
```

But this is not stop taking input even after pressing Enter Key.

Edit - [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20511159/accepting-input-till-newline-in-python) question asked for taking input until empty input but my question is taking input in one line until user press Enter button.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accepting input till newline in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20511159/accepting-input-till-newline-in-python)

Comment: _" my question is taking input in one line until user press Enter button."_ That is how the `input()` function works straight out of the box. You don't need any loops. Once you have the input, `split()` it on whitespaces to get a list of the actual inputs

Comment: But I do not know how many numbers the user going to input. The number of input can vary.

Comment: Try `print("1 2 3 4 5 -9 -10 1000".split())` and see for yourself.

Comment: Run this code: `x = input('Gimme some numbers: ')`. See how it works. Try to enter 2 numbers. Then try to enter 10. Does it work in both cases? What's the value of `x`? [Read the documentation for the `input()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input).

Comment: Yes. My bad. It was a very silly question. But thank you all for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Python 3.8, you could utilise the walrus operator here

```
ls = []

while (inp := input("> ")):
    ls.append(inp)

print(ls)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change it to

```
while inp:
    a.append(inp)
    inp = input()
```

When newline will be entered, `inp` is an empty string, which is [falsy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39983695/what-is-truthy-and-falsy-how-is-it-different-from-true-and-false), thus breaking the loop.

Comment: `inp` won't become `None`. [`input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) always returns a string (if it doesn't throw an exception), so `inp` will be an empty string.

Comment: @AbhinavMathur judging by their comment on the other answer, OP also wanted it appended to a list. IDK why they didn't think of just adding an `.append()` line to your code and instead claimed it doesn't work.  :-/

Comment: @PranavHosangadi I added the append statement, what is missing then?

Comment: @AbhinavMathur _"what is missing then"_ nothing! That's my point. Even before you added the append, nothing was "missing" because 1. OP didn't specify that they wanted them appended to a list, and 2. that's a fairly trivial thing to identify and add anyway

Comment: @PranavHosangadi the "accepted" answer would work only on specific versions of python :/

Comment: Don't worry about reputation and answers being accepted! It's all for fake internet points anyway. Your answer will be read by people in the future and if it helps them, that's what Stack Overflow is all about. FWIW, I upvoted your answer.

Comment: Not talking about the points honestly, just comparing the acceptability of solutions in general